# $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{\frac 1{k+\beta}}^{\frac 1{k+\alpha}} \frac 1{1+x} dx=? $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation

Let $0<\alpha<\beta <1$ then $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \displaystyle \int_{\frac 1{k+\beta}}^{\frac 1{k+\alpha}} \frac 1{1+x} dx=? $

**Try**
$\int_{\frac 1{k+\beta}}^{\frac 1{k+\alpha}} \frac 1{1+x} dx=[\ln(1+x)] _{\frac1{k+\beta}} ^{\frac1{k+\alpha}}=\ln \frac {k+\alpha+1}{k+\alpha}-\ln \frac {k+\beta +1}{k+\beta}$
After this I am struggling to find the sum. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ln\frac{k+\alpha+1}{k+\alpha}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\ln(k+\alpha+1)-\ln(k+\alpha))$. Can you see what vanishes now?

Comment: Hint 2: use $\sum_{k=1}^N$ instead of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty$

Comment: @Gribouillis Certainly, it is a bit easier. :-)

Comment: Thank you all. It's clear to me now